# How would a electrostatic lens accelerate a continuous beam of electrons?

Tags: optics, electrostatics, electrons

Truthfully, I am somewhat confused by this topic. Electro-magnetic lenses are created by coils, through which one runs a current, which then in turn generates a magnetic field whose field lines are more or less donut shaped. This is easy and clear.

Now I am trying to do the same for an electrostatic lens and find myself struggeling. I know that rods are used but since there is no magnetic field, there are no field lines. Ok, I can live with that.

But something I need to understand is how an electrostatic lens could accelerate a continuous stream of electrons which passes through it. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_lens

Answer (score 1):

As with a magnetic lens the electrostatic field between conducting electrodes is configured to produce a converging lens.
Assume that it is positive changes which are being deflected an a very much idealised arrangement.

The arrangement of three cylindrical conductors and their relative potentials, and the resulting electric field is shown as the top left diagram and the trajectories of the charged particles are shown top right.

[image]

I think it easiest to understand what happens by using the diagram bottom left which shows the equipotential lines (actually equipotential surfaces in  three dimensions).
The equipotential surfaces are at right angles to the electric field lines.

Now to the gravitational field analogy.
The bottom left hand diagram is a contour map showing a saddle point at position $S$ as shown in the diagram bottom right.
If one moves from left to right one goes uphill (towards a region of higher height) to get to the saddle point and then downhill away from it (towards a region of lower height).
In going from the bottom to the top along the central axis it is downhill to the saddle point and then uphill away from the saddle point.

Imagine projecting a ball from the left along the horizontal axis of the bottom left diagram.
The ball will slow down when moving towards the saddle point and then after passing the saddle point it will speed up with no change in overall speed from start to finish and its trajectory will be a straight line - it will not be deflected because along the central axis there is no component of field perpendicular to that axis.

Now imagine a ball at position $X$ which is moving upwards at a small angle to the horizontal axis.
The ball will be moving uphill and its trajectory will be such that the angle with which its velocity makes with the horizontal axis is reduced until it reaches position $Y$ where its velocity is parallel to the horizontal axis.
The ball then starts rolling downhill getting closer to the horizontal axis at position $Z$ at which position its speed is the same as it had at position $X$.
Overall a collection of charged particle emanating from a point on the left hand side will converge to a point on the right hand side.